# Ubuntu: How to change Dovecot POP3 default port to 110?

Tags: ubuntu, email, dovecot

I was trying to log in to my email from Gmail POP3 feature and I had to try every single port to connect to my mail server.

What's the command on terminal or what file I have to change the Dovecot default port to 110 instead of 995?

Can I change the port to be some other number?

Answer (score 2):

Postfix is an SMTP server, it has nothing to do with POP3. Dovecot is an IMAP/POP3 server and has everything to do with POP3.

995 is standard port number for POP3S (POP3 over SSL), and is more secure than the plain POP3, which uses port 110. Changing the port number does no good for you.

You just need to decide if you want to use the old, insecure POP3 or more secure POP3S option and configure your Dovecot for that.

Comment: POP3 with `STLS` operates on 110. http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2595 It is no less secure than POP3S.